# How can I pass flags to a LLVM pass?

Tags: llvm

I'm implementing a LLVM pass, and would like to turn some options on or off via the command line, especially I'd like to have a -v verbose mode for my pass.

I couldn't find a mechanism for passing command line flags mentioned in any of the docs, does one exist?

Answer (score 12):

The solution I found is to use LLVM's general CommandLine API: http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html

Works as expected in `opt` when loading the pass dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

Another useful trick is:

```
#define DEBUG_TYPE "my-special-name"
```

...

```
#include "llvm/Support/Debug.h"
```

...

Sprinkle a bunch of debug output around:

```
DEBUG(dbgs() << "Original Frame Size: " << FrameSize << "\n" );
```

...

```
DEBUG(Node->dump(CurDAG));
```

Then, on the command line:
... -debug-only my-special-name ...
will get your output.

If your pass is run with the clang front end, you can use:

... -mllvm -debug-only my-special-name ...

Comment: Thanks, this might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one option with two possible values, the easiest thing to do is to register the same pass twice under two different names. I don't know of any general solution, especially something that will work with `opt`.

Comment: Thanks, I found a more general solution (answered myself below).